# Loading source flat file (without identity column) data in a SQL Server table with identity column: SSIS extract

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, etl

I am asked to load data from a flat file source without an identity column into a SQL Server table with an identity column (column also does not allow null).

Is there a way to do this using a SSIS package?

I have data flow task created, the only option while mapping destination column (identity ) is to ignore, and this fails the task while executing the package.

Comment: You could use auto increment on the column or use a scripting task to generate a primary key.

Comment: I am trying to use auto increment but for some reason Default value  in the properties is gray and I can't type NEWID(). Please let me know how you do this "auto increment"

Comment: Auto increment would be set in the table structure, not as part of the package.

Comment: ok that's what I mean, but how do we do that?

Comment: `CREATE TABLE myTable ( ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT )`

Comment: @MarekGrzenkowicz I thought so too. I have this, [VehicleRecordKey] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,  the while mapping I have ignored for VehicleRecordKey. the error is like this "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'VehicleRecordKey', table 'FUP_ETL_DB.dbo.import_Vehicle'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.".

Comment: Do you *know* that nothing else will be adding data to this table during the load or does a solution need to be concerned with concurrent access? Are you able to create a new table or are we constrained with the existing table as is?

Comment: Nothing will add in the table because the task fails. I didn't get the second part of the question, but yes we I can create table. Regarding constrain, I tried to load in both empty and with data populated

Comment: You're loading data into table X. Is there any other process that might be running that is editing the data in table X? Second question is "Can I create table Y and use *that* to load table X?"

Comment: hmm nothing is editing the data in the table x (if already populated) but while I load in table x, the data from flat file is modified to match data type. I am not sure if I can create table y, but I think it is fairly possible, but loading from y to x , I wonder we might run into the same problem. Isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem. This is my dentity column , [VehicleRecordKey] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL.

All I did to execute the package and load into the table without task failure was ***unchecked the Keep identity*** at OLE DB Destination Editor.

Thanks for commenting on the post everyone.